# What is the difference between an SSL protected site with just a green lock and one with a green lock + company name

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

For example, when going to https://www.google.com/ there's just a green lock, but No text.
When going to https://www.paypal.com/, there's a green lock followed by "Paypal Inc. [U.S]"

Is there any difference at all? Are the certificates from different SSL certificate providers and do they differ in price?

Comment: Short Answer $$$.   The difference is called extended validation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

Answer (score 1):

1. **Green padlock but no text**: User is definitely connected to a website who owns
   the domain name shown in the address bar. Also, connection between user and website is encrypted.
2. **Green padlock + Identity name + Location**: Everything mentioned in above point, along with stricter vetting of the organization, to verify its identity by the certificate authority. This is identified by a browser, based on Extended Validation certificate as mentioned in the comments.

*Reference*: This webpage actually uses Paypal and Firefox as examples: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure#w_green-padlock_2

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three types of SSL certificates distinguished by its validation process, Domain Validation, Business Validation and lastly Extended Validation (EV). As I have mentioned all three types are differentiated by its validation process now if you apply for Domain Validation Certificate then Certificate Authority (CA) will only verify your control over Domain Name on which SSL is requested. You have to prove your control over the domain and the business to get Organization or Business Validation certificate.

And to get Extended Validation certificate, you and your company has to pass through strict authentication process even you have to prove legal holding on your business. [Read this article](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/ssl-certificates-and-its-type) which will help you to understand profoundly on various types of SSL Certificates.

Now let us discuss about the simple green lock and the Green Address Bar. If you select any of first two (Domain Validation or Business Validation) then browsers will display green padlock in address bar before the URL. But if you have purchased **Extended Validation (EV) SSL Certificate**, then browser will display Green Address Bar along with your company name and area name.